# replace the default image with the uploaded image in android

Tags: android

I want to display image from the server for particular id if the image exists.If there is no image for that id,I want to display some default image,and then I want to capture the image from camera,crop it, then load that image to server and I want to display that loaded image in the first activity .How can I do this. I have tried some code,But if there is no image in the server it will display a default image but it is not getting replaced with the uploaded image for the first time.If I login again,it is going to display.How to solve this problem?

```
  @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_details);
            {
            String IMAGE_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.x/mobile_app/" + img_path + "/" + img_name;
            new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ProfilePicIV))
                    .execute(IMAGE_URL);
            }


    public void onResume()
        {  // After a pause OR at startup
            super.onResume();
            getIntent();
            String auid_num = auid_s.getText().toString();
            String imei_num = imei_s.getText().toString();
            String img_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("img_name");
            String img_path = getIntent().getStringExtra("img_path");
            //Refresh your stuff here
            SendDataToServer(auid_num, imei_num);
           String IMAGE_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.x/mobile_app/" + img_path + "/" + img_name;
          new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ProfilePicIV))
                    .execute(IMAGE_URL);

        }

  private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }

xml:
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ProfilePicIV"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@drawable/default_image"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: Where is your `DownloadImageTask` method?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Picasso library to show your image from and use your code just to download it. 
     Add this in your build.gradle

```
 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

and use

```
Picasso.with(context).load(uri).error(R.drawable.default_image).into(imageview);
```

Comment: I  tried this one by replacing new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ProfilePicIV)) .execute(IMAGE_URL); But its not working

Comment: use getApplicationContext() if in activity
or getActivity if in fragment